# how do I call the mousedown event in javascript as long as mouse is held down

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am implementing a joystick control where I want to call the mousedown function after every 100msec as long as mouse click is held on by the user. How can I trigger this?

```
    var hammer = Hammer(document.getElementById('joystick'));
    hammer.on("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    hammer.on("mousedown", onMouseDown);
```

the above code only calls mousedown once initially. To trigger it again I have to release mouse button and click again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in jQuery (ripped from code I already had)

```
    var longClickTimer;

    $('#thing_to_click').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        var $$ = $(this);
        longClickTimer = setInterval(function(){
            $$.trigger('click');
        }, 350);
    });

    $('#thing_to_click').on('mouseup', function(e) {
        clearInterval(longClickTimer);
    });

    $('#thing_to_click').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do something
    });
```

in my case the animation takes 350ms to move, so I trigger it every 350ms, you might need something different.

This isn't the 'best' code as you might get duplication of clicks, so your //do something might need to handle that.

Comment: will the artificially triggered             $$.trigger('click');
 have the values of the real mouse event?

Comment: I don't know - you'd need to test it and see.